# Creating variables with random string - Nothing will be printed out on the screen

Tags: java, loops, variables

I'm creating Java Program which one prints out as many For loops as user wants to. I'm creating variables in *for* wih the random -generated string. The user can choose how long the variable will be. My problem is, when I try list my variables for testing this code work, I can't see anything printed out on the screen when I'm using `listVariables()` -method. If I try to put `System.out.println` inside the `generateVariables()`, The new generated strings are in the `ArrayList` -vector. The code is clear, and it will run on console, but nothing seems to be printed out. Where's the catch?

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Silmukkageneraattori {

    //Attributes

    //Change the value for how many loops you want to create?
    private static final int howManyLoops = 5;

    //Next string -array includes all the generated variables;
    private static ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Next value is how long variable name do you want to create?
    private static final int howLongVariable = 2;
    //Next method generates variables

    public static void generateVariables(int how) {
        String temp = null;
        for (int x=0;x<how;x++) {
            variables.add((String)createVariable());


        }

    } 

    //Next method creates variable
    public static String createVariable() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        for (int x=0;x<howLongVariable;x++) {
            sb.append(""+chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length()-1)));
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }

    //Method for listing created variables;

    public static void listVariables(ArrayList<String> varB) {
        for (int x=0;x>varB.size()-1;x++) {
            String var = (String)varB.get(x).toString();
            System.out.println(var);
        }
    }

    //Main -method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateVariables(howManyLoops);
        listVariables(variables);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you cast to String the result of createVariable when adding to variable list?

Answer (score 1):

In the below for loop in this method:

```
public static void listVariables(ArrayList<String> varB) {
    for (int x=0;x>varB.size()-1;x++) {
        String var = (String)varB.get(x).toString();
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}
```

You are running the loop until `x` becomes smaller than `varB.size()-1` (or until `varB.size()-1` is greater than `x`).

However, `varB.size()-1` does not change size within your loop. Thereofre, it will always be be greater than `x` and `x`  will always stay smaller than `varB.size()-1`. Consequently, the loop never runs.

It appears you only want to get one element from `varB`, the first one, so why not remove the for loop altogether and just do:

```
System.out.println(varB.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`for (int x=0;x>varB.size()-1;x++) {` 
to 
`for (int x=0;x<varB.size()-1;x++) {`

Note the change of **>** to **<** in condition in above `for`.

Comment: Oh my godness, what a Syntax error. The complier tells me nothing about that and the program will be terminated immidiately. Thanks a lot, now I can continue working with this one.

Comment: Please select it as answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have used `>` condition so `0` never will be greater then `4`. so the condition required like it start from 0 to 4. till x will be lesser then total varB.size().

```
for (int x=0;x<varB.size()-1;x++)
```

instead of

```
for (int x=0;x>varB.size()-1;x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the *listVariables* method.

You are using a **>** (greater than) rather than **<** (smaller than).

Once *listVariables* is called, x is 0, and varB.size is some value (5). At the test condition, the loop will not be entered since 0 is not greater than 5.